# Installation of Cobertura Eclipse Plugin: "Could not find ecobertura.johoop.de/update"

Tags: eclipse, cobertura, ecobertura

I need to install the [Cobertura Eclipse Plugin (eCobertura)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/cobertura) which shows unit test coverage in Eclipse. (Another link [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ecobertura))

As instructed, I dragged the bar from the site into my Eclipse workspace, and got the following error:

[image]

So I decided to do it differently and go through Install New Software and turn off the "Contact Update Sites" checkboxes. But I couldn't even do that. Even though I turned off "Contact Update Sites" it still says installation is impossible. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

It does look like the site http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update is offline. Is this plugin still supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corbetura is no longer supported by eclipse I guess (Not available in the eclipse marketplace), I faced the same thing and finally ended up using EclEmma. But if you really want to use it, you can try adding the plugin directly into the project via the pom.xml

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

for reference : https://www.baeldung.com/cobertura